# Media Player without Operating System

Tags: operating-system, media-player

I alongwith some friends of mine was having this idea of creating a very basic media player,Say it only plays mp3s(very limited GUI showing the controls of the player).The Tricky part is we wish to do it without any OS.i.e It will be loaded directly from the boot loader and we will read the file off from a pen drive.Is this a feasible project idea.Its a hobby project so there is no time limit as of now. Can someone guide me as to how to proceed?

Comment: An OS  gives you a secured set of api to instructing the hardware to desired tasks. if you are going to write those set api to instructing the hardwares, then you are also writing some kind of OS. Isn't it? though it may not be an OS like windows or unix. 

to play audio or video you need to write the device drivers. and It is possible.

Comment: How would you handle varying hardware without drivers for the audio chipset, video etc? Its possible you could make a single purpose stripped down linux live disk, but I'm pretty sure you'd need some kind of OS just to actually make use of the computer hardware

Comment: Initially we intend to develop it in the commonly found Intel X86 with onboard audio drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this from scratch, all I can say is good luck. Yu'd have to write file system drivers, sound drivers, display drivers, keyboard drivers, mouse drivers, USB drivers, etc. it would be a massive amount of work.

Instead, if you still want to write things like the mp3 codec yourself, you can, but do it on top of an existing Os. You could go with DOS if you wanted, and have at least something built in to work off of. If I were doing this, I'd be going with embedded Linux + x11. But it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks it was definately helpful.. will look more into embedded Linux+X11

Comment: :Is it possible that I can build a small media application on some Linux kernel which consists of only bare minimum essentials like sound,graphics etc and even a filesystem?Can u suggest me some examples of such linux distros?I mean very very small in size..

Comment: Well, you could compile from scratch, but let me do some research.

Comment: @DebarshiDutta - I'm thinking maybe build something on top of DSL (Damn Small Linux) that boots from a pendrive. http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=damnsmall

Comment: well since @DebarshiDutta and I intend to work on the project... here goes nothing! the point of it *was* to get down and dirty in some low-level coding

Comment: @AruniRC: Then go ahead, by all means! I love a bit of assembly myself.